Nonstandardanalysis criterium for Hausdorff-continuity - is it correct?
Preclaimer: My nonstandard-analysis knowledge is mainly over ℝ. So I might have missed some obvious pitfalls.
For a point $a\inℝ^n$ and a set $B\subseteq P(ℝ^n)$ define $d(a,B):=d(B,a):=\inf_{b\in B} \|a-b\|$.
Define on $P(ℝ^n)$ the Hausdorff-distance as
$$
 d_{\mathrm H}: P(ℝ^n)\times P(ℝ^n)\to [0,\infty],\quad (X,Y) \mapsto \max\left(\,\sup_{x \in X} d(x,Y),\ \sup_{y \in Y} d(X,y) \,\right)
$$
Then $d_{\mathrm H}$ defines an extended pseudo-metric on $P(ℝ^n)$.
Now let $f:ℝ^m\to P(ℝ^n)$ be a function. When trying to find out whether $f$ is continuous w.r.t. $d_{\mathrm H}$, NSA tells us that we only need to show that
$$
x\inℝ^m\land y\in{^*ℝ^m}\land  x\approx y\quad\Rightarrow\quad d_{\mathrm H}(^*f(x),^*f(y))\approx 0 
$$
It seems often easy enough to show that $^*d(u,{^*f(y)})\approx 0$ and $^*d({^*f(x)},v)\approx 0 $ for all $u\in {^*f(x)},v\in{^*f(y)}$.
But just because each point has a neighbor that's infinitesimally close doesn't mean that the supremum over all points is infinitesimally close, too.
An easy way out seems to be to assume that the image of $f$ is always compact.
That is, if $f(x)$ is compact for all $x\inℝ^m$, we can use the extreme value theorem to find that from
$$\forall u\in {^*f(x)}:\quad ^*d(u,{^*f(y)})\approx 0$$
follows that $\max_{u\in{^*f(x)}} {^*d}(u,{^*f}(y))$ exists and therefore is infinitesimal. 
(We only need to show for this that ${D_M}(p):={^* d}(p,M)$ is $^*$-continuous, but ${^* d}(p,M)={^* d_\mathrm H}(\{p\},M)$ and ${^* d_\mathrm H}(\{p\},\{p'\})=|p'-p|$, so that is trivial)
Analogously we obtain that $\max_{v\in{^*f(y)}} {^*d}({^*f}(x),v)$ exists and is infinitesimally.
Both together then imply $d_{\mathrm H}(^*f(x),^*f(y))\approx 0$.

I'm honestly doubtful that my proof works out, since I've had difficulties translating the nonstandard-terminology. That is, since $x\inℝ$, we can translate $^*d({^*f(x)},v)\approx 0 $
to a standard limit statement, but $y\in{^*ℝ}$ makes it difficult to translate $^*d(u,{^*f(y)})\approx 0$ to a standard statement.

The problem with non-standard formulations of continuity is that they only apply to standard functions. Otherwise, $f(x)=\tanh(x/\epsilon)$ is continuous for all standard $\epsilon$, so it should continue to be continuous for non-standard $\epsilon$ too. Obviously, the property of S-continuity $x\approx y\implies f(x)\approx f(y)$ ($x,y$ limited) does not apply in the latter case.

How does a (derived) distance for sets play a role in a continuity definition based on points? What is the standard definition for this continuity?

@LutzLehmann The Hausdorff-Metric is continuous wrt itself, and $D_M$ is the special case of it where we fix an argument and let the other argument be a one-element set. So this special case is still continuous wrt the Hausdorff-Metric, but because the distance of one-element sets is just the distance of their elements wrt to the canonical metric on ℝ, we get that $D_M$ as map $D_M:(ℝ,|\cdot|)\to (ℝ,|\cdot|)$ is continuous. And with that, if we do the whole argumentation but with every object transferred from the start, we get that $^* D_M:(^*ℝ,|\cdot|)\to (^ℝ,|\cdot|) $ is $^$-continuous.

If you have a set of hyperreal numbers $S$ then it is guaranteed that there is $s \in S$ such that $s\approx\sup S=:\hat S$. Otherwise, $\hat S-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon\approx0$ would be an upper bound, contradicting $\hat S$ being the least upper bound.
In the following I will drop all the $*$'s on $d$.
A simple application of Transfer shows that the nonstandard extension of the function
$$
  (X,Y)\mapsto\sup_{x\in X}d(x,Y)
$$
is exactly of that same form; similarly for
$$
  (X,Y)\mapsto\sup_{y\in Y}d(X,y).
$$
So there is $x_0\in{}^*f(x)$ such that $$0\approx d(x_0,{}^*f(y))\approx\sup_{x'\in {}^*f(x)}d(x',{}^*f(y)),$$ and similarly there is $y_0\in{}^*f(y)$ such that $$0\approx d({}^*f(x),y_0)\approx\sup_{y'\in{}^*f(y)}d({}^*f(x),y').$$ Thus $$d_H({}^*f(x),{}^*f(y))\approx0.$$

In response to the comment below about translating $\#1$ and $\#2$ to standard language:
You cannot translate $\#1$ unless you quantify over both $u$ and $y$ because they are not necessarily standard. Similarly in $\#2$ you need to quantify over $v$ and $y$.
So for $\#1$ what you have to translate is $$\forall y\approx x.\forall u\in{}^*f(x).\:{}^*d(u,{}^*f(y))\approx0.$$ It's hard to explain how to do this, but it is mechanical:
$$
  \forall\epsilon>0.\,\exists\delta\geq0.\,\forall y\in\mathbb R^n.\: d(x,y)\leq\delta\implies\forall u\in f(x).\:d(u,f(y)) \leq \epsilon.
\tag{$*$}
$$
Now to prove it's equivalent, apply Transfer to $*$ and choose $\epsilon\approx0$ and $y$ such that $y\approx x$. In the reverse direction you get to choose $\delta\approx0$ in order to prove the Transfered $*$. It's not immediately obvious to me how to write this as a limit, but maybe you can.
For $\#2$ what we want to translate is
$$
  \forall y\approx x.\,\forall v\in{}^*f(y).{}^*d({}^*f(x),v)\approx0.
$$
This becomes
$$
  \forall\epsilon>0.\,\exists\delta>0.\,\forall y\in\mathbb R^n.\:d(x,y)\leq\delta\implies\forall v\in f(y).\:d(f(x),v)\leq\epsilon.
$$

So the compactness isn't even necessary! This is quite stunning to see, especially since $y\in{^*ℝ^m}$. I've tried throwing the counter-examples I've found for my attempted translations of the statements at it, and they're all caught. But I'm still struggling as to how one would translate these statements back. I've realized now at least, that we'll need simultaneous limits. Still, $^*d(u,{^*f(y)})\approx 0$ seems to need at least a sequence for $u$, but then for ${^*f(y)}$... do we need two more independent sequences? Should I ask this as a new question?

@ConnFus I'm not sure what it is that you're trying to translate (by which I assume you translate from NSA language to standard language).

The two conditions $#1:=^*d(u,{^*f(y)})\approx 0$ and $#2:=^*d({^*f(x)},v)\approx 0$ into statements $\lim... =0$ that are equivalent. Let's say we want to show continuity in a single point $x_0\in ℝ^m$ for now. Then e.g. I had initially thought that #1 translates to $\forall y\in f\left(x_0\right):\quad {\lim_{p\rightarrow x_0}{{d}\left(y,f\left(p\right)\right)}}_\ =0$. But that is still missing limit points of $f(x_0)$, but not only converging ones, but also diverging ones.

So I'd assume it looks like $\forall (y_k){k\inℕ}\subseteq f\left(x_0\right):\quad {\lim{p\rightarrow x_0}{{d}\left(y_n,f\left(p\right)\right)}}_\ =0$, where I'd still want to eliminate the $\forall$ by somehow replacing it with yet another limit. As for #2 though, I'm completely lost.

I would not think in terms of sequences, I would use epsilons and deltas and go from there. See my edit

Thank you, this is great! Mechanically parsing #1 it into limits gets you $\lim_{y\to x} \sup_{u\in f(x)} d(u,f(y))=0$, which is, without the limit, exactly one of the arguments of the $\max$ in the Hausdorff-metric. #2 gives the other, and with the limits, we get the continuity-test. I asked the question in part because, if the statement was right, then so I thought, it must do something very different than the straight up continuity test, because it looked so different in description. but with the mechanical parsing we get that it's just the straight translation into NSA! Beautifully simple.

"If you have a set of hyperreal numbers $S$ then it is guaranteed that there is $s \in S$ such that $s\approx\sup S=:\hat S$ " : Can you elaborate on this step?

@MikhailKatz Like I said, if this were not the case then for all positive $\epsilon\approx0$ you would have $$\forall s\in S.:s<\hat S-\epsilon$$ contradicting $\hat S$ being the least upper bound.

Is $S$ bounded?

@MikhailKatz Yes, I was assuming $\sup S$ exists and is not valued in the extended (hyper)real numbers. Though actually unbounded $S$ also works since a reasonable definition of $s\approx\infty$ is that $s>0$ and $s$ is unlimited.
